# How do we know how the Romans pronounced Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, pronunciation

A [quick Google Search](http://community.middlebury.edu/~harris/LatinBackground/Pronunciation.html) says plenty of things about Roman Latin pronunciation, and since it's an edu domain I'm inclined to believe it. However, the closest to citing a source it gets is saying "we know from grammarians"; it doesn't say anything specific.

How do we know how Romans pronounced Latin?

Comment: I've always had this question. The best explanation I once got was, that they had pronunciations examples with greek words in their grammarians. I'm not sure whether this person made this just up...

Comment: I first read this title as "How do we know the Romans spoke Latin?" and *had* to click through to read the question. `:-)`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A standard work in this area is [*Vox Latina*](https://books.google.com/books?id=aexkj_0oj3MC), by W. Sidney Allen.  The author answers your question in his foreword, identifying 6 types of evidence:

> 1. specific statements of Latin grammarians and other authors
>      regarding the pronunciation of the language;
> 2. puns, plays on words, ancient etymologies, and imitations of natural sounds;
> 3. the representation of Latin words in other languages;
> 4. developments in the Romance languages;
> 5. the spelling conventions of Latin, and particularly scribal or epigraphic
>      variations; and
> 6. the internal structure of the Latin language itself, including its metrical patterns.

The evidence for some sounds, of course, will be stronger than for others:

> The degree of accuracy, with which we can reconstruct the ancient pronunciation varies from sound to sound, but for the most part can be determined within quite narrow limits.

Briefly, here are examples of each of these six points from Allen's work:

1. **Latin grammarians**.  Prominent rhetoricians and grammarians instructed their students in proper pronunciation.  For example, Cicero described the [pronunciation of the diagraph *ch*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/648/12), and Priscian and Velius Longus attempted to explain the [sound of the final -*m*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/935/12).
2. **Plays on words**.  Cicero gives a frequently cited example of this, providing evidence that [*v* was pronounced as [w]](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/319/12), when he equates the sounds of *Cauneas* and *Caue ne eas*, which would only make sense if the *u* of *caue* was similar to that of *Cauneas*.
3. **Word borrowing**.  Latin shared vocabulary with Greek and other languages, with both languages borrowing from each other.  The letters used in transcriptions of these words give clues into the Latin sounds.  For example, [evidence for *n* being pronounced as [ŋ] before certain consonants](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/539/12) comes from transcriptions from Latin to Greek and vice versa.
4. **Romance languages**.  The development of Romance languages like Spanish from Vulgar Latin is sometimes helpful with respect to pronunciation.  For example, the [relative lack of aspiration in voiceless stops (p, t, c, qu)](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/637/12) is suggested by the lack of aspiration of these stops in Romance languages.
5. **Spelling**.  The conventions and variations of Latin spelling provide helpful pronunciation clues in a number of cases.  For example, thanks to widespread spelling confusion, we can trace changes in the [pronunciation of the *u*-consonant](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/326/12) back to the first century.  Similarly, inscriptional evidence is used to establish the [length of vowels before “gn”?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/787/12).
6. **Structure and meter**.  The meter of Latin poetry is particularly helpful in ascertaining the lengths of vowels, such as in determining the correct pronunciation of the [names of the letters of the alphabet](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/733/12).

Comment: "_puns, plays on words, ancient etymologies, and imitations of natural sounds;_" Interesting, and entirely sensible. Does the author go on to specify how narrow those limits are? (I'd read your link but I'm on mobile ATM and Google Books seems to be optimized for being bad on mobile)

Comment: @QPaysTaxes This particular book doesn't get into the details too often, except where there is significant disagreement; he points readers to less accessible scholarly works on the respective points.

Comment: It's been a while since I've read Allen, but does he include misspelled graffiti in "epigraphic variations"? That's my favorite source.

Comment: @JoelDerfner I haven't found any specific examples of that yet, but I wouldn't be surprised.

Comment: I find this fascinating, as I was taught "Church"  Latin at school. I can just about cope with *Kikero* for Cicero etc, but, starting again 50 years later, still struggle with *weeny, weedy, weeky* for *veni, vidi, vici*!  ;)

Comment: @TheHonRose I'm pretty sure it's "Wheny weedy weeky" -- it's not "vini", but "veni".

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Well, according to *1066 and All That* (an excellent history reference book, btw) when the Ancient Britons heard Caesar say "weeny, weedy, weeky", they thought he was describing them and gave up in despair.  :(

Answer (score 18):

An important source of information is comparison to other languages.

For example, Cicero was spelled as Κικέρων<sup>1</sup> in Greek.
If we believe that the Greek kappa was pronounced as /k/ rather than /s/ or /ts/ or anything else, we can be confident that c was pronounced as /k/ in Latin as well — at least in this name.

Similarly, the name Caesar gave rise to the present German word Kaiser.
The loan was, as far as I know, made in the ancient times.
If we know something about how the pronunciation of German(ic languages) evolved, we know something more about how Caesar pronounced his name.

---

<sup>1</sup>
Thanks to chirlu (see comments) for the correct Greek accent and the final nu.
I don't know if the final nu was used in all occasions, but that is besides the point.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense, but it raises another question: How do we know how Ancient Greek is pronounced? I'd assume that's mostly by parallel with modern Greek. (Please don't answer that particular question; this feels like it's a rabbit hole with fewer answers than questions for a while, and comments aren't for more questions anyway)

Comment: @QPaysTaxes, if we have theories for how Greek and Latin were pronounced at the time, the spelling of the name gives a consistency condition between them. The two theories are consistent if c and kappa behave similarly (at least in this word). If we are more certain about Greek than Latin, we can use this consistency condition to infer ancient Roman pronunciation, but it could also be used the other way around.

Comment: There is actually suspicion that German _Kaiser_ may be based on a so-called spelling pronunciation, i.e. based on someone trying to make sense of the written form _Caesar_; this is because other evidence suggests that _ae_ no longer was a diphthong already in Caesar’s time.

Comment: Plutarch in his _Parallel Lives_ uses Κικέρων (adding the -ν for names of the type _-o_, _-onis_ was common, as was conversely dropping it when Greek names were used in Latin).

Comment: @chirlu, thanks for your comments! I edited the post slightly regarding the Greek spelling of Cicero.