# Why does "urgueo" exist as a variant of "urgeo"?

Tags: etymology, verbs, pronunciation, phonology

The rule I learned for the pronunciation of the digram "gu" before a vowel in Latin was /gw/ after "n", vs. g + vocalic u anywhere else. But I just discovered the exception *urgueo* /urgweoː/. This is a variant of the verb *urgeo.* A search of the PHI Latin texts corpus for #urgu shows fairly wide usage, so I think that *urgueo* was not just a marginal or late variant.* I can't figure out why *gu* is present here; can anyone explain it?

The form *urgueo* doesn't seem to be discussed in de Vaan 2008, and the etymology given there for *urgeo* doesn't provide any explanation for the presence of an alternative form with a labiovelar: de Vaan says urgeo is from a PIE root with ǵʰ.

I am aware of third-conjugation verbs that also show variation between stem-final "g" and "gu", but those make more sense to me because the stem-final consonant is in some inflected forms brought before a rounded vowel, which is a context where sound changes neutralizing the contrast could occur. For example, de Vaan says *stinguo* comes from a root **stengʷ-*, and that alternative forms with plain g like *stingo, stingere* can be explained as caused by the development of *stingunt* as a simplified form of *stinguunt.*

De Vaan says that the forms *tinguo* (alongside *tingo*) and *coinquo* have non-original /w/ by analogy, but I think that this analogy would have been helped by the neutralization discussed in the preceding paragraph. I've seen other sources that say that *ungo* existed as a (non-etymological) variant of *unguo;* like the previously discussed examples, this is a third-conjugation verb.

De Vaan indicates that in *langueo,* the only other second-conjugation verb that I know of ending in *-gueo,* the *gu* was derived from PIE *ǵ followed by *u. That doesn't seem to help much in explaining *urgueo,* unless there is a some way that an optional **u* after the g could be included in this word's etymology.

Was *urgeo* close enough in meaning to *stinguo* for the latter to have influenced the form of the former, even in the absence of any phonetic factor facilitating the replacement of *g* with *gu* between *r* and *e*? That seems odd to me, but maybe it's the best explanation. Is anyone familiar with a discussion of how this variant might have arisen?

---

*If anyone can better inform me about the distribution of *urgeo* vs. *urgueo,* I would appreciate it. I know that scribes sometimes altered the spelling of words when copying texts, but based on what I've seen so far, I don't think *urgueo* can just be attributed to postclassical scribes. It does strike me as a little odd that the works of Cicero and Ovid contain both *g* and *gu* forms.

Comment: You've really researched your question very well, as always. I have nothing to offer, except that Lewis & Short say *urgeo (less correctly urgueo).* I wonder why, looking at the great number of authors using the form. // Perhaps this is irrelevant, but are we sure it was /urgweoː/ and not /urgueoː/?

Comment: @Cerberus: I'd guess that we know from poetry. I haven't looked at all the examples of its use in verse, but for example I see "urguet opus spernitque deum festumque profanat" in Ovid Metamorphoses 4.390 seems to scan as ur.guĕ.tŏ|pus.sper|nit.quĕ.dĕ|um.fes|tum.quĕ.prŏ|fā.nat

Comment: Ah, yes, it really doesn't scan otherwise, should have looked at a few examples myself.

Comment: Re: their distribution, the OLD says the following: "*urgu*- freq. in post-Augustan times, and occ. read in earlier authors"

Comment: @Asteroides I don't understand your comment above. Urget and Urguet (assuming a digraph *gʷ*) would scan the same. If the second *u* is vocalic, it wouldn't scan. I don't have a critical text of the *Metamorphoses* at home, so I can't check, but the Perseus edition at least is *urget*. Granted it's 19th century...

Comment: @C.M.Weimer: Cerberus's question was why /urgueoː/ with vocalic u wouldn't be a possible pronunciation of urgueo.

Comment: @Asteroides Ah, sorry, read too fast.