# Are vowels long before "gn"?

Tags: classical-latin, pronunciation, consonants, vowel-quantity

Allen and Greenough, [§10d](https://books.google.com/books?id=Q7cAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA5), provide a general rule:

> A vowel before ns, nf, **gn**, is long: as in cōnstāns, īnferō, **māgnus** [emphasis modified]

This seems to agree with Priscian:

> 'gnus' quoque vel 'gna' vel 'gnum' terminantia longam habent vocalem paenultimam, ut 'rēgnum', 'stāgnum', 'benīgnus', 'malīgnus', 'abiēgnus', 'privīgnus', 'Pelīgnus'. ([Keil, II.82](https://books.google.com/books?id=RMBDgH3dq9AC&pg=PA82))

However, Priscian does not mention *magnus*, and Lewis and Short [disagree with A&G and say it has a short vowel](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmagnus1). Interestingly, Bennet includes *ns* and *nf* in his parallel rule, [but does not mention *gn*](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/15665/15665-h/15665-h.htm#sect5).

So which is it?  Are vowels before *gn* generally long or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, it's important to note that *syllables* containing a vowel + *gn* combination are long (or, less confusingly, "heavy"), regardless of the length of the vowel itself.  As Bennet says:

> A syllable is long,—
>   a) if it contains a long vowel; [...]
>   c) if it contains a short vowel followed by x, z, or any two consonants ([5.B.1](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/15665/15665-h/15665-h.htm#sect5))

It does not follow, however, that the *vowel* preceding *gn* is necessarily long.  For that, we'll need to turn to other sources.

W. Sydney Allen addresses the matter in [*Vox Latina*, 71ff](https://books.google.com/books?id=aexkj_0oj3MC&pg=PA71):

> It is commonly, and mistakenly, believed that vowels in Latin are regularly long before the consonant-group *gn*.

Allen contends that:

- The "rule" rests on a single passage in Priscian
- The passage in Priscian is an interpolation, not original
- Historical evidence frequently contradicts the rule
- Only a few words—*rēgnum, stāgnum, sēgnis,* and *abiēgnus*—are likely to have a long vowel preceding *gn*

First, Allen addresses Priscian, and argues that the passage quoted above, in Keil II.82, is an interpolation first based on context:

> The interpolatory nature of the '*gnus*' passage is strongly suggested by its irrelevant interruption of the discussion of proper names, more particularly those with adjectives in *-īnus*; and by introduction of nouns into a chapter which is exclusively concerned with adjectives.

The interpolator, Allen continues, misinterpreted Priscian's discussion of *Anagnīnus*, where the vowel following *gn*, not preceding it, is long. Furthermore, the examples of the rule are not convincing: in several we would expect a long vowel for historical/phonological reasons, while many common words, for which we have evidence of a short vowel, are not mentioned.  Allen summarizes:

> It seems most probable, therefore, that what the interpolator states as a general rule is not so, and that he was at a loss to cite much more by way of example.

Turning to inscriptions, Allen says "we nowhere find even so common a word as *magnus* marked with a long *a*."  There is some evidence for a long *i* in a few of the interpolator's examples, but Allen suggests that this could be explained by phonetic influences on the short *i* before [ŋ] that made its quality (not length) approach that of the long *ī*.  This explanation is corroborated by long *ī* appearing occassionally in front of other inscriptional instances of [ŋ], like *ng, nc* and *nqu*.

Thus, Allen concludes:

> We may safely say, then, that the vowel is long in *rēgnum, stāgnum, sēgnis, abiēgnus*, but probably NOT before *gn* in any other instances.

Comment: I think it is really boring when people pose a so-called “question” and then “answer” it themselves.

Comment: @fdb Sorry it bothers you!  For what it's worth, I don't see it as a "so-called" question; it's something that I came across while reading and wanted to know more about it.  I decided to research it, and found a satisfactory answer, so I thought I would share my findings.

Comment: Also, for reference: ["Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions."](https://latin.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)  Of course, you are free to disagree!

Comment: @fdb, what Nathaniel explains is precisely the reason why self-answering is allowed in the SE network. This is a repository of interesting questions and answers. It is somewhat irrelevant who the authors are. Sometimes it happens that a user asks a colleague about a problem and the colleague can help. If the colleague is not a user and unwilling to become one, it is an excellent idea to share the new knowledge via our site (with proper acknowledgement in such case).

Comment: But it does become rather stupid when people are allowed to up- and down-vote their own questions and answers.

Comment: @fdb Not sure what you mean: I can't vote on my own question or answer here.

Comment: Good. Some of the other forums on here do explicitly allow it.

Comment: @fdb Maybe Reddit or other forums, but not Stack Exchange; voting on your own content is not possible on any SE site.  And I agree, that's a very good thing.

Comment: Even though this thread of comments really belongs on meta, I'll add this: I feel its better to allow a day or two between question and answer to give other users the chance to produce their own worthwhile answers.

Comment: @andy256 I've considered that option as well, but I usually don't do that because a) I might be wasting other people's time if I have an answer ready to go and they, not knowing that, put effort into an answer of their own, and b) there's always the option of answering *after* my answer.  If the other answer is good, I'll upvote it, and if it's better than mine, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 8):

There is some inscriptional evidence that has been interpreted as indicating that short *-ĭ-* before *-gn-* was lengthened to *-ī-,* or perhaps remained short but was raised in quality from [ɪ] to [i].

That said, this evidence seems fairly weak and ambiguous to me. Furthermore, the testimony of the Romance languages indicates that any lengthening or raising of *-ĭ-* that occurred in this context was either subsequently reversed, or simply did not run to completion: for example, Italian has [e] in *degno* and *segnare.* Most recent sources that I've read only mark a vowel before *-gn-* with a macron if it is etymologically long. But for some recent contrary views, see Alex B.'s answer to [What is the correct vowel quantity for words formed from sĭ̄gn-?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/18728/what-is-the-correct-vowel-quantity-for-words-formed-from-s%C4%AD%CC%84gn)

Relevant inscriptional evidence is mentioned in Allen 1989 (*Vox Latina,* pp. 72-73; cited in Nathaniel's answer) and Leumann 1977 (*Lateinische Laut- und Formenlehre,* §127, p. 113). I think the most complete description I've found so far is in Lindsay 1894 (*[The Latin Language: An Historical Account of Latin Sounds, Stems and Flexions](https://books.google.com/books?id=o9akwAEACAAJ&pg=PA138#v=onepage&q&f=false),* p 138), which mentions:

- `prIvIgno` (*Corpus Inscriptionum Latinarum* vi. 3541)
- `dIgne` (*Corpus Inscriptionum Latinarum* vi. 6314)
- `sIgnum` (*C.I.L.* vi. 10234), `sIgnificabo` (vi. 16664)

Leumann mentions inscriptions `seignum` "D 44" and "`sIgnum` 353": I'm not sure what the source for these is (the table of abbreviations says D = Diehl).

I think this evidence is arguable because even though the tall *i*  symbol `I`, called *i longa*, is thought to normally represent long /iː/, it was not exclusively reserved for this function, and there is also some possibility of accidental use. Fortson 2008 says of *i longa*

> one nonetheless has to be careful with interpreting this symbol: in many cases it was merely decorative, being used for I's that stood at the beginning of a paragraph or in certain high-profile words such as *Imperator.* See the discussion and examples in Christiansen 1889. I examined the difficulty of interpreting the use of both I longa and the apex (a symbol used to mark vowel length) in Fortson 2004, after the completion of which another study on this topic came to my attention, García González 2001, unfortunately unavailable to me and not published in the proceedings of the conference at which it was given.

(*Language and Rhythm in Plautus: Synchronic and Diachronic Studies,* Benjamin W. Fortson IV, [page 127](https://books.google.com/books?id=RYWW_2EcJ3YC&pg=PA127&lpg=PA127))

---

*A separate sound change that raised etymological **ĕ* to *i* before *-gn-* was clearly complete already in Classical Latin. This is usually interpreted as a change of *ĕŋ to ĭŋ (found also in the context of original *ĕŋg and *ĕŋk). What's arguable is whether *-ĭgn-* then underwent a further change from [ɪŋn] to [iːŋn] or [iŋn].