# Does an ig- prefix mean there's an underlying g in the root?

Tags: morphology, prefix, phonology, phonetics

There seem to be certain words in Latin which start with an underlying `/gn/`, such as *noscō* `/gnosko:/` `[nɔsko:]`—this "hidden" `/g/` appears when prefixes are added, as in *cognoscō* `/congnosko:/` `[cɔŋnɔsko:]` (with the prefix *con-*).

If we see a word that starts with *ign-*, is that a sure sign of such an "invisible" `/g/`? For example, can we say with confidence that *ignāvus*, *ignōbilis*, and *ignōrō* have an underlying `/g/` in their stems?

EDIT: I'm particularly interested in words that show clear prefixing—*ignis*, for example, doesn't count.

Comment: Related: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/11241/how-was-gnosco-pronounced

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer would be no. *Nōmen* is a well-known example of a word that did not historically start with a velar consonant but that has a velar in some related prefixed words: *agnōmen, cognōmen, ignōminia* (but not in *praenōmen* or *prōnōmen*). This is thought to be the result of analogy.

> There seem to be certain words in Latin which start with an underlying /gn/

I wouldn't put it this way. Words like *nōscō** **historically** started with a velar consonant. It's much less obvious that an "underlying" /g/ continued to be present at the start of words like *nōscō* after they came to be pronounced with initial [n], and spelled with initial <N>.

This topic is covered extensively in *[Aspects of the Phonology and
Morphology of Classical Latin](http://real-d.mtak.hu/896/7/dc_1106_15_doktori_mu.pdf),* by András Cser (2016). See Chapter 11, "The issue of〈gn〉-initial stems" (pp. 194-205).

Cser suggests a phonological development from a form with **gn**, to a form with a dorsal "floating C-Place node" before **n**, to a form with initial **n**:

> it is clear that the literary period saw the gradual disappearance of the floating C-Place node and the lexical split of words in which it occurred. The unprefixed forms were relexicalised with a single initial [n], whereas the prefixed forms were relexicalised with a fully specified [ŋn] sequence which was no different from the [ŋn] sequence found internally in the *regnum* and
>   *ignis*-type words, and from this point on the relation between these unprefixed
>   and prefixed forms was no longer motivated phonologically. This made it possible
>   for other prefixes to attach to 〈gn〉-initial (now phonologically [n]-initial) stems, hence the novel formations like *renatus* ’born again’, *praenoscere* ‘know in advance’, *pernobilis* ‘most noble’.

(p. 202)

---

*My understanding is that <nosco> was pronounced with a long ō in the first syllable: [noːskoː]. I've asked a [separate question about that topic](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/11329/what-evidence-points-to-a-long-%C5%8D-in-the-first-syllable-of-n%C5%8Dsc%C5%8Ds-present-tense).