# What are the classical names of the letters of the Latin alphabet?

Tags: classical-latin, pronunciation, alphabet

When I refer to letters in Latin, I (sadly) use the English names for them.  If I knew the Latin names, I could apply Classical Latin pronunciation rules to say them properly.

So, how was each letter referred to in Classical Latin?  How do we know?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'll briefly summarize the analysis of W. Sydney Allen in *Vox Latina*, 111ff., which is itself a summary of A. E. Gordon's *The Letter Names of the Latin Alphabet*.

First, the vowels.  These have the phonetic value of the letter in its long form: *ā, ē, ī, ō, ū*.  This is well established both by grammarians (Allen cites Pompeius, "quando solae proferuntur, longae sunt semper," *Commentum Artis Donati*) and use in poetry, where the hexameter demands that the lone vowel is long:

> A primum est, hinc incipiam, et quae nomina ab hoc sunt

Turning to consonants, most of the plosives (*b, c, d, g, t*) have a vowel, ē, added to the end of them.  The fact that the added vowel is an *e* is attested by grammarians, while the length of it is established by the meter of a number of works of poetry.

The two plosives that don't follow this rule are *k* and *q*.  Their names, according to grammarians and other sources, are *cā* and *cū*, respectively; this is likely a result of ways these letters were commonly used (frequently *ka-* and *qu-*)

The letter *h*, an aspirate, receives relatively little attention, but some grammarians give its name as *hā*, with the vowel quantity demonstrated by meter.

The remaining letters in the original Latin alphabet, *f, l, m, n, r, s, x*, represent sounds that can be prolonged (unlike the plosives), allowing them to form independent syllables and therefore, theoretically, to be named simply by sounding them (without the addition of a vowel).  This may have been the practice of some, but a system attributed to Varro adds *ĕ*, a short vowel, in front: *ĕf, ĕl, ĕm, ĕn, ĕr, ĕs, ĕx*. Some writers, influenced by Greek, name *x* as *ĭx*.  This system apparently prevailed (it is found in Priscian, among others), but one alternative system we are aware of employed a short vowel before and after, to form the disyllabic names *ĕffĕ*, *ĕllĕ*, etc.

The letters *y* and *z* were not originally members of the Latin alphabet.  The earliest name of *y* may have been *hy*, from Greek, but later this would have been confused with the name for *i*, so it was given the name *y graeca*, pronounced as *ī graeca*.  The letter *z* took its Greek name, *zēta*.

So, the names of all the letters are:

```
A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    K 
ā    bē   cē   dē   ē    ĕf   gē   hā   ī    cā

L    M    N    O    P    Q    R    S    T    U
ĕl   ĕm   ĕn   ō    pē   cū   ĕr   ĕs   tē   ū   

X            Y                 Z
ĕx or ĭx     y ([ī]) graeca    zēta
```

Comment: That's pretty the same as the current German names of the letters.

Comment: @K-HB: And as Dutch, too1

Comment: I have two objections to the names of each letter: 1. It doesn’t show the names of 3 letters, J, V and W. 2. In my opinion, each of the names don’t really look like the right way of spelling them.

Comment: @CraigLungren To answer your objection: J, V, and W didn't exist during Classical times. Why do you think it's not the right way of writing them?

Comment: @CraigLungren A couple or remarks: 1. If you want to figure out why those three letters are missing, you can ask a separate question. If you want to know why the names of the letters are that way, please ask another new question. 2. I converted your answer into a comment, as it was a comment to the answer by Nathaniel. If you ask some well phrased questions, you should soon enough 
earn the reputation to leave comments. 3. As a Finn, I see that also the letters Å, Ä, Ö are missing from the list. I believe most Finns are easily convinced that those were not used in Latin.

Comment: @K-HB And other Central European as well, I believe (Czech and Slovak for sure).

Comment: V existed, U did not