# Can I pluralize letters of the alphabet?

Tags: declension, alphabet

In English, it's very common to talk about letters of the alphabet in the plural: *he writes his R's backwards*, for example, is a perfectly natural sentence. But [the Latin names for the letters](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/733/406) don't seem to follow any declension pattern.

If I wanted to pluralize (or more generally, decline) a letter name, how would I go about it? Are they indeclinable? *y* at least seems to be feminine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I doubt that the letter names themselves were ever declined, but I expect that if the need arose, one could use *litera* in apposition, e.g. *literae R*.  (I expect that's why you say "*y* at least seems to be feminine" - from an implicit *litera* assumed.)

P.S.  I now see that W. Sidney Allen cites quite a few quotations in Appendix A of his *Vox Latina*.  There seem to be usages of letters treated both as neuters and feminines (but I think mainly feminines).  There's far too much there for me to type out by hand, but scanning the citations I see things like

> u litteram digamma esse
>
> u autem, quamuis contractum
>
> e quae sequitur
>
> inter litteram n et g est alia uis
>
> r: non multum est
>
> Maiiamque geminata i scribere

Comment: Entirely fair. I say *y* appears to be feminine because it's sometimes called *y graeca*, not e.g. *y graecum*.

Comment: Is this attested anywhere?

Comment: @Draconis I don't know; I was basing my answer on a reasonable supposition.

Comment: Entirely fair, just curious.

Comment: @Draconis With respect to your remark about _y graeca_: one might compare this with its corresponding later Greek (Byzantine) name, υ ψιλόν / y-psilon, rather than (say) υ ψιλή, from an implied γράμμα.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the good suggestion to use *littera* together with the letter, you can also use a plain adjective, pronoun, or numeral when they are needed.
That is, you could render "he writes his R's like so" as *sua R scribit sic*.
If you want to have an implicit *litteras*, replace the neuter *sua* with *suas*.
I would not decline the letter itself, as the names don't really conform with Latin declensions.

Comment: Is there any attestation of this showing e.g. which gender would be used?

Comment: @Draconis There must be some attestations if you have no limits for how recent it can be. For me both neuter (no noun implied) or feminine (*littera*) make sense.

Answer (score 5):

Some additional examples:

Nam ‘divus’ et ‘rivus’ et ‘clivus’ non ‘us’ syllaba terminantur, sed ea quae per duo u scribenda est ... (Gellius)

est tamen quando idem Aeolis inveniuntur pro duplici quoque consonante digamma posuisse (Prisc.)