# Use of Greek article in Latin to clarify use of foreign indeclinable nouns

Tags: greek, word-usage, articles

This [question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/7294/can-i-pluralize-letters-of-the-alphabet) concerning the pluralization of letter names has led me to ask a somewhat related question on the use of Greek to clarify indeclinable nouns in Latin.

The background to this question is that I possess a Hebrew Bible edited by Everardus Van der Hooght and printed in 1833, but which I think represents amendments to an earlier tradition.  Van der Hooght provides a Latin preface, dated, I think, 1705 (I think that's what CIↃ IↃ CC V represents), in which he discussed various technical points of the Hebrew text.  In particular, he sometimes uses Greek articles to clarify the use of indeclinable Hebrew terms.  For example:

> Præter hanc notam absentiæ τȣ* Dagesch, ...

This is the only place I've seen that usage, so I was wondering anyone has seen it used elsewhere in similar situations.

* that should be τοῦ with ου ligature and circumflex

Answer (score 7):

I happen to have seen one in Marracci's *Refutatio Alcorani* (1698), Prodromus, Vita Mahumeti, Caput 24 (https://books.google.nl/books?id=HwY_AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA29):

> ... ne fortè ... per technas Imperium à se **τῷ Aly** destinatum præriperent.

Literally: "... lest perhaps ... they would by artifices snatch away the Empire destined by him **for Ali**."

Elsewhere he has no problem using an indeclinable 'Aly' as a genitive ("Ismael filius Aly"), dative ("præcepit patrueli suo Aly"), accusative ("in fratrem Aly filium Abutaleb") or ablative ("Auctore Aly filio Ebrahim").

---

I've also found one in a letter from a Vandevalus to a Craneveldt around 1520 (https://books.google.nl/books?id=101lb8v-bJcC&pg=PA47):

> Nam **τὸ "al"** articulus est Araborum ...

I.e.: "For **'al'** is the article of the Arabs ..."

IJsewijn *et al.* note:

> The use of the Greek article in Latin to single out a word is a
>   humanistic usage. Mediaeval Latin authors used either the
>   demonstrative "hoc" or a newly coined article "li" or "ly".

By 'humanistic' they must mean 'neo-Latin'.

---

Here are some more, from Tanquerey's *Synopsis theologiae dogmaticae* (1921), Tomus II, p. 288 (https://archive.org/details/synopsistheologi02tanq/page/228):

> *Omne quod movetur, ab alio movetur.* Hoc patet consideranti naturam
>   motûs seu **τοῦ *fieri***. Etenim : i) motus  seu **τὸ fieri** est unio
>   successiva diversorum; ...

"*Everything that moves, is moved by something else*. This is clear to someone who considers the nature of movement or **(of) *becoming***. For: i) movement or **becoming** is the successive unity of diverse things; ..."