# Why is Q so dependent?

Tags: classical-latin

Why does Q always need a U right after it? What's the meaning behind it? Like every word in Latin that has a Q always has a U behind it. Why is that?

Comment: Related: [What's the deal with Q?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/5378/79)