# Was there a standard accent in Latin in the Roman era?

Tags: classical-latin, roman-culture, vulgar-latin, dialects

I know that the standard language was Classical Latin and that the average person spoke Vulgar Latin, but was there a standard dialect or pronunciation for Latin? Like the way it was spoken in Rome?

Comment: Since you know of the difference between Vulgar Latin and Classical Latin, what do you mean by "standard dialect" – the standard dialect *is* Classical Latin, so what is your question?

Answer (score 3):

Considering the number of times that Roman senators made fun of people with provincial accents ([Hadrian](https://books.google.com/books?id=gVXFkh-tlBcC&pg=PA61&lpg=PA61&dq=hadrian+provincial+accent&source=bl&ots=f725NioTJM&sig=ACfU3U2R5mD67NqgjC5GWDlU8jcZwNJvsQ&hl=en&ppis=_c&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjru92e6NjnAhUUJzQIHYVDBjgQ6AEwB3oECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=hadrian%20provincial%20accent&f=false) is a good example), you could probably argue that whatever was spoken in Rome was what was closest to being considered the "standard" or "correct" way to pronounce Latin. On the topic of pronunciation, you might find [this post on how it is that we know how they pronounced Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/66/how-do-we-know-how-the-romans-pronounced-latin) interesting.