# Are any phonemic distinctions not represented in Latin?

Tags: example-request, orthography, spelling, phonology

Latin orthography seems to have been relatively phonemic. In other words, if long vowels are marked somehow (macrons or apices), there seems to be a straightforward mapping between letters and phonemes in the language.

Are there any real exceptions to this: Classical-era phonemic distinctions that aren't represented in spelling?

(I know long vowels are often left unmarked, so that *alium* and *ālium* look the same. But for the purposes of this question, assume vowel length is marked consistently and reliably.)

Comment: @Asteroides Given that there are near-minimal pairs like _iambus_ vs _jam_, that one would count! I'm not sure if there are any similar cases for u/v.

Comment: Would something like *abicere* spelt with I but pronounced as JI count? You can't deduce pronunciation from spelling, but I don't know of a minimal pair for this.

Comment: The answer may differ for different dialects. Do you mean the classic pronunciation? For medieval ones it might a lot more complex.

Comment: @PavelV. Good point. I'll narrow it down to Classical.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I'd also count that, alongside things like the final consonant in _hoc_. Anything that makes it more difficult to determine the pronunciation from the spelling.

Comment: @draconis Tour question asks whether Latin orthography is phonemic.   Your last comment asks whether it is phonetic.  Perhaps you should post that as a separate question?

Comment: @CMonsour I don't know of any minimal pairs for final _c_ versus _cc_, but consonant length is definitely phonemic in general; likewise, for Joonas's suggestion, there are near-minimal pairs like _abit_ with `/i/` versus _abicit_ with `/ji/`.

Comment: I wasn't commenting on the first sentence of your remark, nor on the preceding discussion, just on "Anything that makes it more difficult to determine the pronunciation from the spelling".  Phonemic spelling DOES make it harder than phonetic spelling to deduce pronunciation from spelling--you have to know the alternations and rules for realizing each phoneme.

Comment: @CMonsour I should clarify—anything that makes it more difficult to determine the pronunciation of an unknown word from the spelling, given native knowledge, a copy of _Vox Latina_, or something similar that covers the realization rules. For example, _G_ realized as `[ŋ]` before nasals isn't a problem, because it's completely regular; _I_ being sometimes `/i/` and sometimes `/ji/`, though, is an issue, because there's no way to know which is the case for an unknown word.

Answer (score 5):

The fairly obvious:

- Latin orthography is incapable of distinguishing /i/ from /j/, /jː/ (*eius* /ˈejːus/), and /ji/ (*adicio* /adˈjikioː/). These are phonemic distinctions: <i> between vowels is *almost* always /jː/, but it's /j/ in e.g. *Gāius*; <i> between a not-vowel (word boundary or consonant) and a vowel other than another <i> is *almost* always /j/, except in loans like *iambus* /iˈambus/; /ji/ isn't marked at all, because it doesn't "naturally" occur anywhere except in zero-grade compounds of *iaciō* (e.g. *adiciō* /adˈjikioː/), where the /j/ is sometimes restored by analogy (but actually *adiciō* /adˈikioː/ is also attested).
  (Conversely, I expect but have not confirmed the distinction between <ī> and <ii> is spurious at least some of the time.)
- /w/ and /u/ are also certainly separate phonemes in Latin: there's a minimal pair in *volvit* /ˈwolwit/ 'he rolls' and *voluit* /ˈwoluit/ 'he wanted', spelled the same.

Also, the diphthongs *ae* /aj/, *eu* /ew/, *oe* /oj/, *au* /aw/, and *ui* /uj/ are not distinguishable from the corresponding sequences of two vowels: *cui* /cuj/ vs. *fruitur* /fru.i.tur/. *Eu* as a diphthong exclusively shows up in Greek loans and the interjection *(ē)heu*; in native words, possible confusion is limited almost entirely to a few instances of *ui* in practice.

The Greek phonemes that got their own spelling (*ph*, *th*, *ch*, and *y*) were certainly not separate phonemes for most Latin speakers. Likewise, *pulcher* was surely /'pulker/, not /ˈpulkʰer/, for almost everyone.

For a more out-there tack, a case could be made that vowel nasalisation, which was not reflected in writing, might have been phonemic for educated speakers:

The [well-known](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/43/was-the-final-m-a-full-featured-consonant) instance of nasalisation is before word-final *-m* (*mālum* [ˈmaːlũː]), which is perfectly regular so you don't really need to represent it in writing: it's allophonic. It also happens regularly before a nasal consonant followed by /s/, and this is where it possibly breaks down:
E.g. *consul* [cõːsul] is frequently written as *cosul*, which is a non-phonemic spelling but can be dismissed as just an error; certainly the spelling *consul* also persists. It persists so hard, even, that eventually the *n* is restored to the pronunciation of the word, which is now [cõːnsul], still written *consul*: the nasalisation has become phonemic, and it is not represented in the spelling.

This is admittedly not an uncontroversial statement: all we know for sure is that in common speech, the *n* in these positions was not pronounced and the vowel was lengthened compensatorically (this is what we see reflected in the Romance languages, and also mentioned explicitly and implicitly by contemporary grammarians), and that educated Romans did tend to pronounce the *n* but also keep the vowel long (stated explicitly by Cicero and various grammarians). As far as I know the nasalisation is imputed entirely on typological grounds (Allen does not specify, and I'm away from my other books at the moment; the Romance languages all lost nasalisation everywhere so it's impossible to tell based on the descendants), but eminently plausible; that this nasalisation would be preserved in educated speech does not strike me as unlikely (especially since even the likes of Cicero neglected to pronounce the *n* in some words, surely with nasalisation there), but isn't directly confirmed.

It is, at least, a thing to consider.

Comment: How about _eu,_ which I understand can mean a diphthong as in _Europa_ and _eheu_ or two syllables as in _eum_ and _aureus,_ and is not marked by a diæresis in any period's spelling conventions?

Comment: @BenKovitz I though about *(ē)heu* but I rejected it for the same reason I would reject the idea that tutting means English has a click phoneme, and apart from that I don't think there's any native word that has *eu* as a diphthong, but you're right that *Europa* is a prominent loan I forgot about. There's actually a few others, like *eulogia* and *eunuchus* (also the title of a play by Terrence). I'll amend.

Comment: Don't you mean that the nasalization in *consul* was phonemic *before* the N was restored, rather than after? When the N is there the nasalization is predictable.

Comment: @TKR No, Vns > Ṽːs is perfectly regular (the nasalisation is effectively allophonic), Vns > Ṽːns is not.

Comment: Are you saying that [Ṽːns] contrasted with [V:ns] for some speakers? What's the evidence for that?

Comment: @TKR I'm saying that Ṽːns (possibly!) contrasted with Ṽːs for some speakers, including Cicero, who certainly had an *n* in *consul* but apparently not in certain other words (Velius Longus (2nd C., admittedly): "Cicero *foresia* [= *forensia*] et *Megalesia* [= *Megalensia*] et *hortesia* [= *hortensia*] sine N litera libenter dicebat.").

Comment: Right, but my point is that the relevant contrast there is between [Ṽːs] and [V:s], e.g. *cõsul* vs. *rōsa*. What made the nasalization phonemic was the loss of the conditioning factor [n], regardless of whether it was subsequently restored in some forms. That is, if Cicero said [forẽsia] then he had phonemic nasalized vowels, whatever his pronunciation of *consul* was.

Comment: @TKR That's not necessarily an illegitimate analysis, but it's not the way nasalised vowels are usually analysed in Latin, which is through mediation by a placeless nasal, which also does *not* trigger nasalisation in certain other phonetic contexts (see e.g. András Cser's *Phonology of Classical Latin*); I don't doubt the main reason this is done this way is because of the spelling. The important bit in *this* context is that nasalisation is regularly reflected in orthography except for people like Cicero.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123061/discussion-between-tkr-and-cairnarvon).