# Verbum Hispānicum "mientras" significat "-m" fīnāle prōnūntiātum esse?

Tags: pronunciation, spanish, late-latin

In [Was the final “-m” a “full-featured” consonant?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/43/779), cēnsēbant "-m" fīnāle prōnūntiātum nōn esse, sed faciēbat nāsāle vōcālem praecēdēns. Sed invēnī verbum Hispānicum "mientras" ex linguā Latīnā "dum interim" vēnisse. Quōmodo exstat "m-" incipiēns in verbō "mientras" sī "-m" fīnāle in verbō "dum" nōn prōnūntiābātur?

**English summary**: Does Spanish "mientras" < Latin "dum interim" imply that "-m" in "dum" was pronounced?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think the /m/ of *mientras* implies a great deal about the pronunciation of Latin *-m* beyond what is already known from other sources.

*Mientras* is clearly not just the regular outcome of applying Latin-to-Spanish sound changes to Latin *dum interim.* If so, it would not end in *-ientras;* Latin *interim* should go to *entre* with no final *s* and no diphthongization of the tonic vowel. The presence of these irregularities makes me think that /m/ could possibly be another irregular development in this word, rather than a sound that was preserved from a feature of Latin pronunciation.

#### It has possibly been analogically influenced by the adverbial suffix *-⁠mientre*

In *A History of the Spanish Language,* Ralph Penny does give the usual etymology from *dum interim* > *domientre* > *demientre* > *mientras,* but says that the "diphthong results from the influence of the Old Spanish adverbial ending *-mientre* < *-MENTE*" (page 247).

The /r/ in the form *-mientre* possibly shows influence in the opposite direction, from *domientre* (Penny 132). (However, an alternative etymology of *-mientre* traces the *r* to the Latin adverb-forming suffix *-ter*: *[Syntax and Affixation: The Evolution of MENTE in Latin and Romance](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Syntax_and_affixation/yHgbDgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22mientras%22+%22mientre%22+etymology&pg=PA95&printsec=frontcover),* Keith E. Karlsson, §5.7.2.)

If the *ie* in *mientras* was caused by influence from *-mientre*, it doesn't seem too implausible to me to suppose that the /m/ might also be influenced by *-mientre,* through a development like [dõentre] > [domɛntre] or [don entre] (compare the [n] that developed in the monosyllables *quien, con*) > [domɛntre].

#### possible alternatives to the etymology from *dum interim*

While the etymology you give seems to be widely acknowledged, there is a paper from 2011 that presents other etymologies: "Nueva hipótesis sobre el origen del adverbio medieval 'm(i)entre'." Javier Mora García.

García's paper is in Spanish, so I don't understand the details of the arguments. THe first novel proposal gets rid of *dum,* although it looks implausible to me: *en entre* > *enentre* > *de enentre* > *denentre,* then, supposedly by an dissimilation of nasals, *dementre.* The second involves *dum,* just like the standard etymology.

However, the third etymology García proposes gives a regular explanation for the /m/ as not coming from Latin word-final *-m*, although I don't know if I'm convinced by it either. He suggests *mientras* could be ultimately from *interim* + *-mente* with alteration of the second element and then loss of the initial *entre-.* A form *entrementre* is attested in French, and *entrementes* is attested in Galician-Portuguese.

Ultimately, I don't get the sense that the standard etymology is convincingly displaced by any of these, but it seems like something to consider.

### Latin final *-m* might have had [m] as a possible pronunciation, even if "mientras" by itself is weak evidence for it

For the reasons above, the /m/ in *mientras* doesn't seem very strong evidence in and of itself for supposing [m] in the pronunciation of Latin *dum.*

However, there are unrelated reasons to think [m] might have been at least a possible occasional pronunciation of word-final "m" before a vowel in Latin.

- The most obvious is the spelling. Latin spelling is mostly phonetic, and the letter "m" definitely could represent [m] in other contexts in Latin words. Early on, when Latin spelling conventions were first formed, the sound was presumably felt to be similar to [m] (one fairly common suggestion is that word-final *-m* could be realized as a nasalized glide [w̃], which like [m] is a nasal and labial non-syllabic sound). And after Latin spelling had become conventionalized, the force of spelling pronunciation presumably could have introduced [m] into the speech of literate speakers.
- The etymological source of Latin final *m* is reconstructed in Proto-European as *m, which is normally assumed to have been pronounced as [m]. One small piece of evidence that survived in Latin itself for [m] as the etymological value of final *-m* is the form of the verb *comedō,* whose etymology is typically given as from *edō* and the prepositional prefix corresponding to *cum* (which usually took the form *co-* before vowels).
- Lastly, there are references in grammars to a fault of speech "mytacism" or "moetacism" that was in some way connected to the pronunciation of "m". It's not always clear what a grammarian means by it, but some cases seem to refer to pronouncing the word-final /m/ of accusative words as [m] before a vowel (Nyman 117).

The consonant [m] is not considered to have been the usual pronunciation of word-final Latin *-m* before a vowel because of the regular occurrence of elision in this context: we find *singultantem animam et* in Ovid pronounced as six syllables, long-long-long-short-short-long, which fits perfectly with [singultant‿anim‿et] and is not really compatible with any pronunciation where the *-m*s are [m]: [singultantm‿animm‿et] has an awkward cluster after the third syllable and looks like it would have a long fifth syllable.

#### Works cited

- *A History of the Spanish Language*. Ralph Penny. Second ed. 2002.
- "Nueva hipótesis sobre el origen del adverbio medieval 'm(i)entre'." Javier Mora García. *Anuario de Lingüística Hispánica,* ISSN 0213-053X, Vol. 27, 2011, págs. 127-144
- "Mytacism in Latin Phonology". Martti Nyman. *Glotta* 55. Bd., 1./2. H. (1977), pp. 111-120 Published by: Vandenhoeck & Ruprecht (GmbH & Co. KG). Accessed through Jstor.

Comment: +1! But I miss the hypothesis that _dum interim_ was at some point a cultism. That could explain both a regular pronunciation and a different history of sound changes. Or is this idea just implausible?

Comment: Re: "If the *ie* in *mientras* was caused by influence from *-mientre/-miente/-mente*, it doesn't seem too implausible to me to suppose that the /m/ might also be influenced by *-mientre*": That seems like a stretch to me, sorry. /me/ and /mje/ are similar enough that it's plausible for /me/ to become /mje/ due to a bit of influence from a similar-sounding-but-semantically-unrelated form with /mje/; but for /e/ to become /mje/ requires a lot influence from a neither-similar-sounding-nor-semantically-related form. What would cause that?

Comment: @ruakh: I'm not sure exactly how I think it would have worked, but what I was imagining was that the development to /m/ would have occurred from a form that had not been entirely denasalized. So not /e/ > /mje/, but maybe something like [õe] > [omje] or [one] (compare the monosyllables *quien, con*) > [omje].

Comment: @Asteroides: Ah, I see; that makes much more sense. Thanks for clarifying. :-)